# can you pass router-view as a prop in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Is it possible to pass  as a prop when calling another component?

Essentially, I have components, and views, I build my views using various components. I want to have 1 styled component which I can reuse, so I was thinking to have a `WebsiteLayout.vue`:

```
<template>
   <a-layout-content :style="{ padding: '0 24px', minHeight: '280px' }" />
       {{ content }}
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "View",
  components: {
  },
  props: ["content"],
};
</script>
```

And in my `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <Content content=<router-view /> />
</template>
```

This isnt correct, but wondering if something like this is possible, and how I could achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

With Vue 3 and Router 4, you can do something like

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <SomeComponent>
    <component :is="Component" />
  </SomeComponent>
</router-view>
```

and then

```
//SomeComponent.js
<template>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <slot></slot>
 </div>
</template>
```

[here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#route-based-dynamic-transition) is an example with `transition` component as a wrapper for the router-view component

to know more about scoped slots you can see [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Destructuring-Slot-Props)